# AngularJS : ui-grid-resize-columns don't seem to take effect. Leads to title row growth

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use angular ui-grid. I have included the appropriate injects as follows in the controller.

**controller.js :**

```
    'use strict';
    //'ui.grid' is dependency injected into angular
    var bbApp = angular.module('bbApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection',    'ui.grid.resizeColumns']);

    // Below is the code to allow cross domain request from web server through angular.js
    bbApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
    ]);

    bbApp.controller('BBCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = function() {
      var url = '/members'; // URL where the Node.js server is running 
    queryWalltimeList();

    // Accessing the Angular $http Service to get data via REST Communication from Node Server
    function queryWalltimeList() {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        $scope.walltimeList = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.walltimeGrid = { 
    data: 'walltimeList',
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false, 
    enableFiltering: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Design', width: "65%"},
      {field: 'walltime', displayName: 'Memory', width: "35%"}
    ]
    };

    $scope.walltimeGrid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
      //set gridApi on scope
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;    
    };
    };
    $scope.list();
});
```

**My HTML :**

```
<section>
    <div ui-grid="walltimeGrid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns class="bb-grid">
</section>
```

**My CSS :**

```
.bb-grid {
  width: 300;
  height: 200;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

All the modules are available and accessible. But when the table is rendered, resizing does not occur.

[image]

Comment: Try rendering the grid inside a `$scope.on();`

Comment: I didn't quite understand. I'm very new to angular. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to wrap `$scope.walltimeGrid = {` in a `$scope.on();`  ( I am not sure if this will work , it worked for me using datatablesjs

Comment: No that does not work. The scope is seems to be set correctly which is why the data and other features are loaded. The problem is that the vertical scrollbar inside the grid is visible and not enabled. I think this is causing the title row to expand to the overall table size.